# Unable to play webM file on chromium with Media Source Extensions. Works in firefox and vlc

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm, media-source

I'm currently trying to implement a video player using Media Source Extensions. Currently just a very simple proof of concept, following a tutorial I found [here](https://www.wirewax.com/blog/post/building-a-media-source-html5-player-with-adaptive-streaming-25).

I cloned their repo with all source code from github [here](https://github.com/wireWAX/media-source-tutorial.git) and am testing the implementation on Chromium and Firefox with various video files.

Everything worked well with the example webm files in the repo for both browsers.

Next I tried to convert a video I downloaded from some random site using ffmpeg and [mse-tools](https://github.com/acolwell/mse-tools) to "align the clusters" of the webm file using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i randomvideo.mp4 -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis output.webm
mse_webm_remuxer output.webm aligned.webm
```

Again, all was well on both browsers.

Finally, I wanted to convert a very simple animation I created in blender (rendered with h264 in mp4).

I tried converting the resulting file using the same process as above and the file played normally on firefox, but did not load on chromium.

I assume I am commiting some error when converting the file, but inspecting the attributes of the final file with vlc and ffprobe, I could not find any obvious problems.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

One final test I did was to go to [this site](https://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/) to get some sample webm files.

I downloaded the "Big Buck Bunny Trailer in WebM" and "Elephants Dream as WebM File".

Both files worked in firefox, but the "Elephants Dream" file would not play in chromium.

I am on a linux machine (Arch Linux distro) with the following versions of the browsers:

> Chromium Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)
>
> Firefox 62.0.3 (64-bit)

I have shared the file I created from the blender animation (very small - only 36 KB) on google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gaEGV47KSx98A7mHtjgDH5jq-iu4t56_) in case anyone wants to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after banging my head over the weekend, I finally figured out the problem with my tiny blender rendered mp4 file. Posting it here in case anyone has a similar problem.

I tried converting my original mp4 file with various other software suites to see if ffmpeg was doing something that was making my final webm file incompatible. Tried a couple of online converters and a comercial video converter (trial copy), but all had the same result. No video with MSE. Then, by chance I converted it using KDENLIVE. Not really a conversion, but rather a "rendering" as if it were a video editing project. To my surprise, it worked! Upon inspecting the diference between the files, I noticed that KDENLIVE added an audio stream to the webm file.

This led me to the realization that the original file without audio was generating a webm file with mime type of `'video/webm; codecs="vp8"'`(and not `'video/webm;codecs = "vp8,vorbis"'`). So the solution for me was to either change the mimetype passed to `addSourceBuffer()` or to generate the webm file with a muted audio stream (thus creating a file of type  `'video/webm;codecs = "vp8,vorbis"'`).

Both solutions above worked and my file was able to play in chromium.

Just as a final side note, the "Elephants Dream" file from this [webm demo files site](https://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/) still is not playing as is, but I did "re-render" it with kdenlive, and also reencoded it with ffmpeg, and in both cases, the new file worked. So I believe, there may be some issue with the original file.